# what does =! means in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I came across this line while reading source code of an application.

```
$scope.editMode = ! $scope.editMode;
```

I wonder what does this is not the not the not equal to operator. I tried it in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/11377/) the answer is correct but I still do not understand the logic is this somehow an equal to operator?

jsfiddlecode

```
  $scope.name = 'Superhero';
        $scope.hero = '123'    
        $scope.name = ! $scope.hero
```

Comment: It means assign to NOT it. It's just `x = not x`. So if `x = true;` then `x = !x;`, now `x == false`

Comment: Do you know what the `!` operator does by itself? i.e. do you know what `!x` does?

Comment: Also good the give a look on `coercion`

Comment: It's the same as `$scope.editMode = (!$scope.editMode)` if that's easier to read, it turns `$scope.editMode` into a boolean, false if it's truthy etc. In other words it's a "switch/flag", turning falsy values into true, and truthy values into false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**!** is used to reverse boolean value. 
For example:

```
!(true) = false and 
!(false) = true
```

In your example
, reversion of $scope.editMode value has been assigned to itself.

Comment: Perfect Thank you

Comment: @Imi, you are welcome.